# If a question is answered by a collective's article then what action should be taken?

Tags: discussion, collectives

None of the choices that jump to mind seem great:

1. You could close the question as a duplicate (I suspect this may be the correct action but it is unintuitive to me)
2. You could post a link to the article (though this would become a link-only answer)
3. You could copy/paste the article content into an answer (two sources of truth, potential for either side rotting)

Comment: Related: [Allow voting to close questions as duplicate of Articles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408667/11682469)

Comment: You roll your eyes and complain about how you can do absolutely nothing about it. You can't close articles as dupes of questions, and you can't close questions as dupes of articles. Welcome to double redundancy with the added bonus of allowing rep abuse by spewing out articles about content that already exists, and questions on the same topic as an article. Also note that option #3 is [generally plagiarism](/help/referencing), and that self-reposts tend to get deleted. I actually have no idea how self-reposts work when the source is an article, though.

Comment: The moderation systems around articles are non-existent for even mods, at least last I checked.

Comment: i think it os a good idea to close questions, hen an article exists. That is a function that is really needed, as long as articles and collectives are existent that is

Comment: SInce there's noway to do this, there's option 4. Pretend the article doesn't exist. Write your own Answer in your own words and post it.

Comment: @Zoe A cited answer is never plagiarism. I think it's safe to assume that Pace isn't intending to copy the content without citing the source properly.

Comment: @Catija "Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own." - some cited content is still deletable, and fully copying a text with no extra content is most definitely delectable under that rule.

Comment: @Zoe you specifically called it plagiarism. What you're citing is correct policy but that doesn't make the content plagiarism. I'll also point out that you again seem to be assuming the worst. Pace's answer says "two sources of truth", which to me clearly implies that option 3 would include supporting content by the answer author.

Comment: Given that Q&A has been here for years and articles just barely started, I'd say it's much more likely new articles parroting what has already been asked and answered several times than vice versa. | Anyway, they've been presented as something distinct from Q&A, so don't really see how the concept of duplicates is relevant there.

Comment: Right.  This sounds like a different discussion.  FWIW, in my mind, my viewpoint was that of an article author coming across a question and wanting to help.

Comment: @Catija that's not how I read it. It doesn't strictly speaking imply inclusion or exclusion of supplying content as written. I also said "generally", not "always", and linked to the help document to avoid it seeming purely negative or one-sided.

Comment: A: downvote the question for not being properly researched (articles do appear in search) or B: downvote the article for not being clear enough to be found by the asker.

Comment: I give this whole "collective articles" thing 6 to 8 weeks before they phase it out like they did with documentation after the beta. It makes no sense.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli the difference this time is that collectives represent a partner relationship; it all depends on what contractual obligations there are whether features tied to collectives can be altered or dropped just like that.

Comment: @Gimby well, that just makes the whole thing worse if you ask me...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Do the same as with other sources that you take information from:

- Refer to the source, *and*
- Recite the key points from the source *that are relevant to the specific question*

E.g.:

> As per [the article](https://www.example.com/), you:
>
> - foo the bar
> - baz the xyzzy
>
> ```
> <sample code>
> ```

Comment: This makes sense.  I suppose this same conundrum happens with any other blog post or even 3rd party official tutorials.  Also, it makes sense that questions will probably target particular parts or pieces of any lengthy article.

Answer (score 19):

None (specific). Collective articles are currently not part of the ecosystem in any relevant way (most people cannot edit them or close them or post alternatives). I suggest to treat them as any external content for the time being (there aren't many articles anyway).

Simply treat articles as any other external source (option 3 in your case).

If you want to reduce the redundancy, either don't post articles or request a better integration of articles.